# Regex: select text that doesn't match given criteria

Tags: regex

I have a large set of data of the following generic structure:

```
corn@icopia.com asgasdgasdfas ted@todd.com
asdfasdfasdf fred@tail.net.ed homer@illiad.com asdfasdfa
```

I want to select everything this isn't an email address. I know how to select e-mail addresses `([^ ]*@[^ ]*\.[A-Za-z]*)` but I do not know how to negate the result and select everything except the email addresses.

Any guidance you can offer would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Select where? Different apps/script languages can have different regex engines.

Answer (score 2):

`(*SKIP)` & `(*FAIL)` verbs are your friends.

Use : `\S+@\S+(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|\S+`, it matches everything that is not an email address.

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/axd92Q/1)